# How to logout from su-ed root at certain time

Tags: bash

Suppose, the user does `su`, switching to `root`

```
$ su
Password: 
bash-4.2# crontab -l
```

How can I logout all such users from `root` at a certain time?

#### What I tried

I know, that using this command:

```
bash-4.2# ps -A -u root | grep bash
 2303 tty1     00:00:00 bash
 2548 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 3040 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 3080 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
```

we can get all the Bash shells, owned by `root`. But how can I select the one that was generated by `su`? When I ran `echo $$` in the su-ed shell, it gives this:

```
bash-4.2# echo $$
3040
```

Then I tried:

```
bash-4.2# kill 3040
```

But it didn't kill the `root` shell. Plus if I create a `cron job echo $$` it won't give the necessary PID. So, this won't work.

Now I'm stuck.

Comment: You must have security problems that transcend this one, because your having a lot of sudo'ed users can be indicative of other problems.  Setup a script that immediately forks a child. The child sleeps n seconds. It then does a kill -15 $PPID  (or whatever is SIGTERM on your system) and exits.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). Why do you need this? Are you running `su` in a cronjob?

Comment: @terdon +1 this was what I wanted to say, more succinctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To kill all bash processes, belonging to root, I used the following script:

```
for pid in $(pgrep -u 0 bash); do
    if [ "$pid" != "$$" ]; then
        kill -HUP "$pid";
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

`pkill -u 0 su` alls all `su` processes running as root (which in turn kills their child shells).

If you only want to kill the bash processes running under `su`:

```
for pid in $(pgrep -u 0 bash); do
  parent_pid=$(ps -o ppid= -p "$pid")
  parent_command=$(ps -o comm= -p "$parent")
  if [ "$parent_command" = "su" ]; then kill -HUP "$parent_pid"; fi
done
```

That being said, this is probably a bad idea. What if that shell you're killing is doing something important?

If you want to kill shells that remain unattended for too long, set the [`TMOUT`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-TMOUT) variable in `.bashrc`. For example, with `TMOUT=600`, bash automatically exits if it sees no input for 10 minutes.

Do think carefully about what you're trying to achieve. There's a good chance that killing shells won't solve whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

As other states, it should not be needed. You should see first why there are many `su` processes actives.

On the other hand, to kill all those processes, e.g. under Linux you could use:

```
ps aux | awk '/su( -)?$/ {print $2}' | xargs sudo kill
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about killing off other `su` processes (`su -u username`) the simple approach will be

```
   echo "killall su" | at 1145 jan 31
```

If you care, use Emy's solution, feeding it to "at" for "a certain time" or adding it to crontab for periodic calls.

Note smartass users will overcome Emy's filter with `su -u root` and hunting them down will be hard as `su` takes quite a few options which could fool the regexp. `killall` is more foolproof, but may cause collateral damage as described above.

Answer (score 0):

`pkill` (and possibly its companion `pgrep`) should work nicely, if indeed you really need to do this.

Something like `pkill su` will send a kill signal to all `su` processes. Also look at their `--full` parameter; see the man page for details.

To achieve the "at a certain time", the obvious solution is to use `at`, which is specifically designed to execute a given command at a given time and only then (as opposed to cron, which executes scheduled commands repeatedly when the system time matches some given criteria).

Putting them together, you get something like `echo pkill su | at 17:30`. Note that the `at` will have to be run as root.